# Twitter login not working with twitter app ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterkit

I am implementing login from twitter  in ios objective c. The following code working well if Twitter app not installed in device ,it redirect to safari and login successful from twitter but if twitter app installed it redirect to twitter app but nothing happened. Please help.Thanks

**appdelegate** :

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"xxxxxxxxx" consumerSecret:@"xxxxxxxxxxxx"];

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options {
    return [[Twitter sharedInstance] application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
     (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
      if (session) {
        TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
        NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
        [client requestEmailForCurrentUser:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
            [client loadUserWithID:userID completion:^(TWTRUser *user, NSError *error) {

                NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary new];

                NSLog(@"%@", [session userID]);
                NSLog(@"%@", [session userName]);
                NSLog(@"%@", [session authToken]);
                NSLog(@"%@", [session authTokenSecret]);
                [data setObject:[session userID] forKey:@"userID"];
                [data setObject:[session userName] forKey:@"userName"];
                [data setObject:[session authToken] forKey:@"authToken"];
                [data setObject:[session authTokenSecret] forKey:@"authTokenSecret"];
                if(user){
                    [data setObject:user.name forKey:@"name"];
                    [data setObject:user.screenName forKey:@"screenName"];
                    [data setObject:user.formattedScreenName forKey:@"formattedScreenName"];
                    [data setObject:user.profileImageLargeURL forKey:@"profileImageLargeURL"];
                    [data setObject:user.profileImageMiniURL forKey:@"profileImageMiniURL"];
                    [data setObject:user.profileImageURL forKey:@"profileImageMiniURL"];
                }
                if (email) {
                    NSLog(@"signed in as %@", email);
                    [data setObject:email forKey:@"emailId"];
                    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(twLoginSuccessfulWithData:)]){
                        [[self delegate] twLoginSuccessfulWithData:data];
                    }

                } else {
                    if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(twLoginSuccessfulWithoutEmailData:)]){
                        [[self delegate] twLoginSuccessfulWithoutEmailData:data];
                    }
                }
                NSLog(@"Profile image url = %@", user.profileImageLargeURL);
            }];

            // }
            //                 else{
            //                     if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(twLoginFailedWithError:)]){
            //                         [[self delegate] twLoginFailedWithError:error];
            //     }


        }];

    } else {
        if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(twLoginFailedWithError:)]){
            [[self delegate] twLoginFailedWithError:error];
        }
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Have you added Url scheme in plist ??

Comment: yes , login working well with web but not from twitter app

Comment: Check whether u are logged in Twitter App, if not login in ur twitter app and check again from your app.

Comment: found any solution Brp ?

Comment: i am also facing the same error, but its more worst than this, without twitter app i am getting error, with twitter app the same scenario.